# ng-model doesnt communicate with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've been working on an app for trainers and I have encountered possibly simple 
problem, despite that I dont know how to fix this and I tried many different solutions.
What i've noticed is that it works pretty fine when input is above the list generated by ng-repeat but i want the list to be under the input.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Here is the html code as it is now:

```
<html ng-app="trainingSupport">
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" ng-controller="addOffer">
<div class="span40"><input type="text" ng-model="newOffers.offerName" name="offer" class='span48 offer-in'></div>
<div class="span8 options-btn">
<div class="pencil-offer"><i class="icon-pencil icon-offer"></i></div>
<button ng-click="newOffer()" type='submit' class="btn save-offer"><i class="icon-save"></i></button>
<button type="submit" class="btn trash-offer"><i class="icon-trash"></i></button>
</div>
</form>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
<ol class="span48" ng-controller="addOffer">
<li ng-repeat="offer in offers" ng-bind='offer.offerName' class="unbold f-pt-sans offer-list"></li>
</ol>
</html>
```

and here is the tha angular code:

```
var trainingSupport = angular.module('trainingSupport', []);
function addOffer($scope){

$scope.offers=[
{id:0, offerName:"szkolenie z pieczenia indyka"},
{id:1, offerName:"szkolenie z gaszenia wodą"},
{id:2, offerName:"szkolenia z bicia konia"}
];

$scope.newOffer = function(){

$scope.offers.push({


offerName: $scope.newOffers.offerName
});

$scope.newOffers.offerName='';

}

}
trainingSupport.controller("addOffer", addOffer);
```

Comment: not clear your question. plz explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a jsFiddle for this, and chiseled your code down to the basics, for better readability. 
http://jsfiddle.net/yhx8h/1/

I refactored your controller quite a bit, its much cleaner now.

```
var trainingSupport = angular.module('trainingSupport', []);

trainingSupport.controller("addOfferCtrl", 
function AddOfferCtrl($scope){       

    //this variable is bound to your input
    $scope.newOfferName = '';       

    $scope.offers=[
       {id:0, offerName:"szkolenie z pieczenia indyka"},
       {id:1, offerName:"szkolenie z gaszenia wodą"},
       {id:2, offerName:"szkolenia z bicia konia"}
    ];

    $scope.newOffer = function(){
      //handy little method to grab the max id in your array
      var newId = Math.max.apply(null,$scope.offers.map(function(item){return item.id})); 

      //increment the id, and add new entry to the array
      $scope.offers.push(
        {id: newId + 1, offerName: $scope.newOfferName }
      );     
    };

});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div ng-app="trainingSupport" ng-controller="addOfferCtrl">

  <input type="text" ng-model="newOfferName" />
  <button ng-click="newOffer()" type="button" text="click me to add offer" ></button>

  <ol>
    <li ng-repeat="offer in offers">{{offer.offerName}}</li>
  </ol>

</div>
```

I bound your input to a separate variable, `newOfferName`, and got rid of the extra submit button and the `<form>` tag. Judging from the code you posted, I don't see why you would need to use a `<form>` tag in this implementation, or a submit button.  Instead, you can just bind an `ng-click` function to a button (or almost any other type of element really) which will handle updating your array and re-binding your list.  Finally, I dont see why you need an `ng-bind` on your `<li ng-repeat>`, I removed that as well.  Hopefully this refactored code helps you out!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. However I managed to make it function with my method. Wat I observed is that the difference between the ng-ocntroller node and the ng-repeat node cant be larger than 4. But i really appreciate your contribution and the way You've managed to "pin" the last id number :) thanks